# Trying to download created file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I followed questions on stackoverflow and ended up with the following code

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The problem is the output file is wrong, its in Chinese (encoding probably), i want to know if there is a header for encoding or if its another problem.

Edit:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Pragma: public');
```

Excel preparation code:

```
$iterator = 0;
foreach (get_object_vars($temp[0]) as $key => $value){
    $formattedkey = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($iterator, 1, $formattedkey);
    $iterator++;
    $fieldsnum++;
}

$rowiterator = 2;
foreach ($temp as $asset){
    $coliterator = 0;
    foreach (get_object_vars($asset) as $key => $value){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($coliterator, $rowiterator, utf8_encode($value));
        $coliterator++;
    }
    $rowiterator++;
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Wrong content type for an `.xlsx` file, it should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Are you setting cell values as UTF-8?

Comment: The database connection is in UTF-8, also when saving the file to the server it's created correctly but when i do the direct download the English characters are in Chinese.

Comment: I tried using utf8_encode() but its the same, the characters changed but it's still in random characters.

Comment: I changed the content type as well but same output.

Comment: Headers for encoding are irrelevant, headers are for a web browser, MS Excel isn't even aware that browser headers exist. The charset for an Excel file is defined within the file itself.... but lease provide some example of what you mean by "random characters" because PHPExcel doesn't do "random characters". Show us what you're getting rather than force us to try and guess

Comment: But also, why are you utf8_encoding anything? What charset is the data in your $temp array? If it's already UTF-8, then you shouldn't need to change it in any way. If you do need to change the charset to UTF-8 because it's something different, then use iconv()

Comment: When opening the file it first asks for encoding and type (i am using Libre office not Microsoft office ). Then whatever my choice is the file contains Chinese characters in 2 rows regardless of the content of the actual content

Comment: I added the utf_encode because someone had a similar issue and that solved it for him. I wasn't  using it at first.